# What is the right way of having login form in the master page? - asp.net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am having two issues:

1. I usually create separate view for the login to keep things simple but this time i want to have in the master page. If something goes wrong with the login process i add some error in the modelstate and keep the user to the page he currently is. What is the proper way to construct this, i mean create the current url?
2. In the register view, after submit, if that username exists, i see that model validation error in both validation summary(login form validation summary and register form validation summary).What can i do see the error message only in one particular form validation summary?

All the code is in HomeController but i will rename it to AccountController and keep here only ViewResult Index().

I gladly accept any tips of how to write it better and of course any critics.
Thanks.

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private List<string> questions = new List<string>
        {
            "What is yout pet's name?",
            "What is your birth date?(mm/dd/yyyy)"
        };

        private CustomMembershipProvider mbProvider = (CustomMembershipProvider)System.Web.Security.Membership.Provider;

        public ViewResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginModel logModel, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(logModel.LoginUsername) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(logModel.LoginPassword))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Please enter username and password.");
                return Current_View;
            }
            else
            {
                MembershipUser mbUser = mbProvider.GetUser(logModel.LoginUsername);
                if (mbUser == null)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid username.");
                    return Current_View;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!mbUser.IsApproved)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Go to your email and confirm the registration.");
                        return Current_View;
                    }
                    if (mbUser.IsLockedOut)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Your account is locked.");
                        return Current_View;
                    }
                    bool isValid = mbProvider.ValidateUser(logModel.LoginUsername, logModel.LoginPassword);
                    if (!isValid)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid credetials.");
                        return Current_View;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(logModel.LoginUsername, false);
                        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                        {
                            return Redirect(returnUrl);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return Current_View;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }            
        }

        private void SetRegisterViewData()
        {
            ViewData["Questions"] = new SelectList(questions);
        }

        public ViewResult Register()
        {
            SetRegisterViewData();
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Register(RegistrationModel regInfo)
        {
            SetRegisterViewData();
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                MembershipCreateStatus status;
                MembershipUser user = mbProvider.CreateUser(regInfo.UserName, regInfo.PassWord, regInfo.Email, regInfo.SecretQuestion, regInfo.SecretAnswer, false, null, out status);
                switch (status)
                {
                    case MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateEmail:
                        ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "That email already exists");
                        return View(regInfo);
                    case MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateUserName:
                        ModelState.AddModelError("Username", "That username already exists");
                        return View(regInfo);
                    case MembershipCreateStatus.Success:
                        //SendConfirmationMail(regInfo.UserName);
                        return RedirectToAction("Index");
                    default:
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Error");
                        return View(regInfo);
                }
            }            
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        public ActionResult Logout()
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your validation I would suggest using DataAnnotations.

In LoginModel.cs you can define your criteria and error messages.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class LoginModel{
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = @"You must supply a valid email address.")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public String Email { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Compare("Email", ErrorMessage = @"Passwords do not match")]
    public String ConfirmEmail { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = @"Please enter a password")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public String Password { get; set; }

    //whatever other properties you want
}
```

Then in your controller you can just check for:

```
if(ModelState.IsValid()){
    //do stuff
}
```

If not then return View(logModel) and the errors will be present in that object.

**Appended**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LogInModel loginModel){
    if(ModelState.IsValid()){
        //do stuff if good
    }
    //not valid
    TempData["loginModel"] = loginModel;
    RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
}
```

In the Home ActionResult just add logic to handle the loginModel object which will have the errors in it.

Comment: I will add DataAnnotations validation but i do not have enough place to show property validation error messages that's why i think only yo show model validation error message. If i move the login logic in AccountController   return View(logModel) won't wok because there won't be any ViewResult named Login, i just need to stay on the current view.

Comment: You can return View("NameOfYourActionResult", logModel)

Comment: I will ask another question:How to keep the current on the current page when posting a form isn't successful.

Comment: Ok so you want to do your validation in another controller (AccountController), if that is not successful you want to return the user to the same view they were on with the errors from the model, correct?

Comment: I appended my post, this should set you up nicely.

Comment: When user enters the site he goes to Home/Index, then he may go to some other page that doesn't require authentication, let's say Random/Page/2. Then the user wants to authenticate, he is on Random/Page/2, but he enters some invalid credentials. The error message must appear in the login form validation summary which is in the master page but the user must still be at Random/Page/2.

Comment: If you want to make sure you go back to the previous action you can use Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());